# Weird VueJS Routing behaviour

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an issue with my routing. I have a simple on click handler to push to the router.

```js
methods: {
   page(path) {
      this.$router.push(path);
   }
}
```

which will display the correct content, but the URL **briefly** goes to the correct URL but then goes back to the previous. I only new it was happening because when I clicked the 'back' browser button the URL was then correct.

I opened up the console and decided to test the router

```js
$vm0.$router.push('/my-path');
```

Which not only displayed the correct content but the URL was also correct.

I'm now stumped to how debug this further so if anyone has any ideas please let me know.

router.js

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: require('./views/Campaigns').default },
    { path: '/foo', component: require('./views/Foo').default },
    { path: '/campaign/edit', component: require('./views/EditCampaign').default },
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import router from './routes';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
});
```

Regards

Comment: please, provide the vue-router configuration. Also, do you have any other `router.push` in the destination component?

Comment: Updated question. Nope, I've also set up test routes/views which Is bare bones just for testing purposes.

Comment: What element is being clicked? Is it an `<a>`? If so, you need to call `e.preventDefault()` or `@click.prevent` in the template to prevent the link from changing the URL.

Comment: what a muppet! Cheers @DecadeMoon, add an answer an I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the click event attached to an `<a>` element, so you need to prevent the default click behavior which is to follow the link.

You can achieve this in two ways:

**1. Using Event Modifier**

> To address this problem, Vue provides event modifiers for v-on. Recall that modifiers are directive postfixes denoted by a dot.

```vue
<a @click.prevent="page('/foo')">Button</a>
```

**2. Using Event Handler**

If you need access to the event object:

```vue
<a @click="page('/foo', $event)">Button</a>
```

```js
page(path, e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.$router.push(path)
}
```

This might also apply for click events on other kinds of elements, like buttons inside a form. [Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)